# how to insert new line into a cell in fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have tried using Ln(), MultiCell() or Write(), but I always get weird problems. Like after the 1st row and 6th column, the loops breaks, and the entire layout falls back.

```
foreach($data as $row)
    {
    $room='-1010B';
    $labNo='(L1)';
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    $this->Cell($w[0],15,$row[0],'LR',0,'C',$fill);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $this->Cell($w[1]+$w[2],15,$row[1]. " " .$room,'LR',0,'C',$fill);
    $this->Cell($w[3],15,$row[3]. " " .$room,'LR',0,'C',$fill);
    $this->Cell($w[4],15,$row[4]. " " .$room,'LR',0,'C',$fill);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
    $this->Cell($w[5],15,$row[5],'LR',0,'C',$fill);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    if($row[6]!="")
        $this->Cell($w[6],15,$row[6]. " " .$room,'LR',0,'C',$fill);
    else
        $this->Cell($w[6],15,$row[6],'LR',0,'C',$fill);
    $this->Cell($w[7]+$w[8]+$w[9],15,$row[7],'LR',0,'C',$fill);
   $flag++;

    $this->Ln();


    $fill =! $fill;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the sample script on fpdf.org

http://fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php

You'll want to create an array for each line and use the function Row() which handles multiple lines for you.

To insert a new line use `\n` for example: `This is a\n2 line example`

Comment: \n is not working with Cell() or with MultiCell() , but if you use MultiCell() then it is enough to press Enter and it is it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case symbol `@` worked.

Using method WrapCell:

```
e.g. WrapCell(20, 8, "first line@second line");
```

Comment: Sorry, guys.
WrapCell is a Wrap method written by my predecessor - it's not in fpdf.php ...

Answer (score -2):

```
$pdf->SetXY(10, 44);
$pdf->cell(190,0,'',1);
```

Comment: Can you explain what you have written?